# I have fast internet, but sometimes it hangs and websites load very slowly

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, connection, internet-connection, internet-speed

I'm facing a problem, in so far as my internet speed is good, but a lot of times websites take 5-7 seconds to load, or I have to keep clicking the reload button. I don't think it's right. My speed is about 200 mbps, but from what I've gathered on this forum, it's not a reliable indicator? Can someone suggest how to diagnose the problem?

Edit: Some steps I've already tried to fix it: Clearing caches, resetting the router & device network settings, using some other DNS server. They haven't worked.
Also, I've tried contacting my ISP, they've sort of given up, they're not very good at these technical issues.

So an update: I ran a bufferbloat test on waveform, normally I got an A plus, but when I ran it when the issue was happening, I got a B. I don't know what that means though.

P.S: I'm trying to attach a video of the problem I had taken, but there doesn't seem to be an option for that. If anyone can tell me that'll help a lot.

Comment: What kind of research have you done and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Run TCP/IP Reset and restart, test.   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer
  Also see if you can update the firmware on your router.

Comment: @Albin I haven't found much information on a situation like mine, I did read on many forums though that having good speed alone is not a good indicator of internet problems. I've tried restarting and resetting the router, clearing caches and network information, but that hasn't helped.

Comment: @John I use an iPad, not a windows computer so can you explain if this can be done on it? Also, this router doesn't have an updatable firmware/software (I don't know which is correct in this situation).

Comment: For the iPad, Settings and reset Network settings (then you must reconfigure your network again. If the router firmware cannot be updated, you may need to try a new router.

Comment: What you're describing sounds more like a latency problem than a bandwidth problem. In my experience, the two most common causes of the symptoms you describe are (1) slow DNS lookups or (2) bufferbloat. Try manually setting your DNS server to a known-fast public DNS server like 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 and see if the problem goes away. If that doesn't do it, run the [Waveform Bufferbloat Test](https://www.waveform.com/tools/bufferbloat) and see if you have a bufferbloat problem.

Comment: @John I forgot to mention I've tried resetting network settings already, that didn't fix it. I can look into getting a new router, but it's provided by my isp and it's unlikely they'll allow anything else.

Comment: @Spiff I already use opendns, I ran this bufferbloat test you've linked, I got an A plus. But I ran it when the internet was working fine. Is it supposed to detect a problem otherwise as well or only when the issue is present?

Comment: The bufferbloat test can usually detect bufferbloat even if your network is otherwise idle and performing fine. But it would still be interesting to see what it says during a time when you're experiencing the problem.

Comment: Any reason you haven't called your ISP's support yet? By the way, this is all information belonging INTO the question, not the comments - Please update your question! [How to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Albin thanks for the tip, I've added it into the question. My isp's support has failed to find a problem, they're not very good with this; they just stick to fixing issues like slow speed, break in cables etc.

Comment: @Spiff. I got a B when I tested during the problem. Does that mean anything?

Comment: @Spiff You still there?

Comment: @Johnnytest I'm still here, but I don't have any further suggestions from anything you've added to your Question or in the comments. A "B" at worst on the Waveform bufferbloat test is not a clear indicator to me that your problem is bufferbloat. In fact it makes think it's not.